# Check For Particular Class, If Not There, Then Remove Particular Element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check the body tag to see if has a particular class, if it does not, then remove particular SVG elements. Those SVG elements are inside the header, if that matters. I have tried many variations, but can't quite get it.

This is my latest attempt:

**EDIT**: Added HTML

```
<body class="header-layout-fourteen">
    <header>
       <svg class="wave" viewBox="0 0 960 80" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <path d="M 0,61.61878 C 428.81164,128.05787 670.62027,-50.721079 960,14.619851 L 960,80 0.51812022,80 Z" />
      </svg>

      <svg class="open-book" viewBox="0 0 960 80" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <path d="M 885.51726,0 A 405.62125,84.746301 0 0 0 480.73447,80 L 960,80 960,1.4938023 A 405.62125,84.746301 0 0 0 885.51726,0 Z M 74.48273,0.52138 A 405.62125,84.746301 0 0 0 0,2.0152033 L 0,80 478.66477,80 A 405.62125,84.746301 0 0 0 74.48273,0.52138 Z" />
      </svg>

      <svg class="mountains" viewBox="0 0 960 80" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <polygon transform="scale(9.6,0.8)" points="72,20 85,100 95,50 100,80 100,100 0,100 0,0 15,100 33,21 45,100 50,75 55,100 " />
      </svg>
    </header>
    <main>Main Content</main>
    <footer>Main Footer
       <script>
           $( document ).ready(function() {
               if(!$('body').hasClass('header-layout-fourteen')) {
                   $('.site-header').remove('svg.wave'),
                   $('.site-header').remove('svg.open-book'),
                   $('.site-header').remove('svg.mountains')
                }
            });
        </script>
    <footer>
</body>
```

Comment: No period when passing class names to `hasClass()`. Should be `.hasClass('header-layout-fourteen')`

Comment: @j08691 Thanks, but didn't make it work.

Comment: The you'll need to post a [mcve]

Comment: To me, it meets the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: How? You've posted no HTML. Far from complete or verifiable. We can't see it failing as you claim

Comment: It's not Complete or Verifiable because there's no HTML to create a working example from. That said, I've added an answer for you below based on some common assumptions.

Comment: Give me a few minutes then to try and create one. I don't know how to create that run snippet thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two issues here. Firstly you should remove the `.` prefix on selectors when using `hasClass()`. Secondly, the parameter to `remove()` performs a *filter* on the selected elements, not a *find* operation. As such you need to amend the logic to this:

```
if (!$('body').hasClass('header-layout-fourteen')) {
  $('.site-header').find('svg.clouds, svg.mountains, svg.waves').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear when the body would have this class versus not have this class. But I would advise the following code:

```
$(function() {
  if (!$('body').hasClass('header-layout-fourteen')) {
    $('header svg.wave').remove();
    $('header svg.open-book').remove();
    $('header svg.mountains').remove();
  }
});
```

First, the condition, the if statement suggests that if `<body>` does not have class 'header-layout-fourteen', it is then true. If it's running against your HTML, it will always be false (body.hasClass('header-layout-fourteen') == true, ! makes it false).

Second, I do not see any elements with class 'site-header', so I am guessing that you mean `<header>` or  `$("header")` objects. Since your Header contains SVG elements, with specific classes, you should create more specific selectors:

```
$('header svg.wave')
$('header svg.open-book')
$('header svg.mountains')
```

Then use `.remove()` on the selected items.

```js
$(function() {
  if (!$('body').hasClass('header-layout-fourteen')) {
    $('header svg.wave').remove();
    $('header svg.open-book').remove();
    $('header svg.mountains').remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Example 1
<div class="body-content header-layout-fourteen">
  <header>
    <svg class="wave" viewBox="0 0 960 80" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <path d="M 0,61.61878 C 428.81164,128.05787 670.62027,-50.721079 960,14.619851 L 960,80 0.51812022,80 Z" />
      </svg>
    <svg class="open-book" viewBox="0 0 960 80" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <path d="M 885.51726,0 A 405.62125,84.746301 0 0 0 480.73447,80 L 960,80 960,1.4938023 A 405.62125,84.746301 0 0 0 885.51726,0 Z M 74.48273,0.52138 A 405.62125,84.746301 0 0 0 0,2.0152033 L 0,80 478.66477,80 A 405.62125,84.746301 0 0 0 74.48273,0.52138 Z" />
      </svg>
    <svg class="mountains" viewBox="0 0 960 80" preserveAspectRatio="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
       <polygon transform="scale(9.6,0.8)" points="72,20 85,100 95,50 100,80 100,100 0,100 0,0 15,100 33,21 45,100 50,75 55,100 " />
      </svg>
  </header>
  <main>Main Content</main>
  <footer>Main Footer<footer>
</div>
```

In the example, `<body>` does not have 'header-layout-fourteen' class and items are removed.  if you change the selector to `$(".body-content")` in the if, the items remain.

Hope that helps.